# can i think each httprequest runs with a thread in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to reduce total httprequests time after game launched, but I am confused how httprequest is running in c# , Can i think each httprequest runs on a new thread or always on the main thread ?

Comment: Depends on the host provider. However, generally “yes”: ***each request runs (as soon as it can be processed) independently***. This can be on different threads or even different processes. With the use of async requests (usually async/await) the same threads can be reused for multiple requests. *It is erroneous to assume or expect requests to have implicitly serialized executions*.

Comment: I'd recommend [this article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) about threading in async HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

No. A thread is an execution path that runs in a CPU, and while you are waiting for a remote server to respond to your web request there is no code running in **your** CPU. After the remote server has responded and while it sends packets of data to your PC throw the network, it is the **network driver** of your machine that is doing work and **not your CPU**, so this doesn't count as a working thread either. A thread is utilized at the point that the data have fully arrived and are stored in your RAM, to process these data, assuming that you have actually written code to process them, otherwise your CPU has no work to do. You can read the famous [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) article by Stephen Cleary, for a detailed explanation about what's happening under the hood.

Comment: Ignoring some controversial statements, the question implies a web server side and I don't think that OP is interested in of what happens on a HTTP client side.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov hopefully the OP will clarify the question, otherwise we'll never know for sure.